# Cannot render grouped cells without row count in reactable

Tags: r, reactjs, reactable

I'm using rMarkdown, knitting to html, and trying to do something simple in reactable - use JS to suppress row totals in parentheses. I'm literally copying from their own guide, but its not working:

[reactable Grouped Cell Rendering](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#grouped-cell-rendering)

```
data <- MASS::Cars93[10:22, c("Manufacturer", "Model", "Type", "Price", "MPG.city")]

reactable(
  data,
  groupBy = c("Manufacturer", "Type"),
  columns = list(
    Manufacturer = colDef(
      # Render grouped cells without the row count
      grouped = JS("function(cellInfo) {
        return cellInfo.value
      }")
    )
  )
)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in colDef(grouped = JS("function(cellInfo) {\n return cellInfo.value\n }")) : 
unused argument (grouped = JS("function(cellInfo) {\n return cellInfo.value\n }"))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grouped` argument is not available (yet) on the CRAN version of the package. You can install the development version from github and then the example works.

```
#install the package from github
#devtools::install_github("glin/reactable")
library(reactable)
data <- MASS::Cars93[10:22, c("Manufacturer", "Model", "Type", "Price", "MPG.city")]

reactable(
  data,
  groupBy = c("Manufacturer", "Type"),
  columns = list(
    Manufacturer = colDef(
      # Render grouped cells without the row count
      grouped = JS("function(cellInfo) {
        return cellInfo.value
      }")
    ),
    Type = colDef(
      # Render grouped cells with the row count, only if there are multiple sub rows
      grouped = JS("function(cellInfo) {
        if (cellInfo.subRows.length > 1) {
          return cellInfo.value + ' (' + cellInfo.subRows.length + ')'
        }
        return cellInfo.value
      }")
    )
  )
)
```

[image]